# GIS maps to DWG files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dwg

I'd like to know how do I export a map from Gis to a dwg file (to use it in autocad for architectural needs).
I've tried to watch already a couple of tutorials and also registered to ARCGIS free trial but still can't get it.
Somehow, after I've registered to ARCGIS, I have only a user for the site but don't have any software which I can access from my desktop.
Does someone can help me understand how to I do it?
How can I save a map from Gis and to what format?
And later on, how do I transform this format to a dwg?
Finally, is it necessary to install same plugin in autocad for this purpose?

Comment: For registration (licensing) of your ArcGIS software you might want to talk to Esri or your Esri Distributor. Once you have it licensed it's easy to export your vector data to DWG (see below). If you can't get ArcGIS, you might find QGIS handy.

Comment: With third party software it can be easily done. http://www.guthcad.com.au/arcv2cad.htm this company specialized to export esri shape, dwg, dxf vica versa.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] which says upfront that there should be only one question per question in our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

Open ArcMap: Add the vector data. **Right click the layer** in the table of contents, click **"Data"**, then click **"Export to CAD"**.

[image]

Comment: http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30328